# Clearing UITextfields with UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, uitextfield

I have a page with 5 UITextfields and 1 UItextview. These are a email form, and I want it so when you press the button that sends the email, it also clears the textfields and textview. It is very important that it only does this after the data has been collected for the email, so the email won't be empty.

Code:

```
@IBOutlet var text1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text3: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text4: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text5: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var text6: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.text1.delegate = self
    self.text2.delegate = self
    self.text3.delegate = self
    self.text4.delegate = self
    self.text5.delegate = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}
@IBAction func sendEmail(sender: AnyObject) {     let mailComposeViewController = configuredMailComposeViewController()



if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
self.presentViewController(mailComposeViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
} else {
self.showSendMailErrorAlert()
}
func configuredMailComposeViewController() -> MFMailComposeViewController {
let mailComposerVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
mailComposerVC.mailComposeDelegate = self // Extremely important to set the --mailComposeDelegate-- property, NOT the --delegate-- property
let messageBody = text1.text!+"\n"+text2.text!+"\n"+text3.text!+"\n"+text4.text!+"\n"+text5.text!+"\n"+text6.text!
mailComposerVC.setToRecipients(["wastepin@hotmail.com"])
mailComposerVC.setSubject("New Dumpster")
mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(messageBody, isHTML: false)
return mailComposerVC
```

Picture of page:
[image: Mail form page]

Comment: "It is very important that it only does this after the data has been collected for the email". How does one know the data has been collected? Collected where? You might want to include that part as it's seemingly missing.

Comment: Sorry about that. As i mentioned it is a mail form, and in the code it says "messagebody" and combines all the text fields, that is when the data is collected and made in to an email.

Comment: What if the email doesn't go through though? I noticed you have an error check in your code, although is that all inclusive that it safeguards any other problems? You could also dismiss the view after it's sent successfully and leave data in the fields with an optional "clear fields" button perhaps.

Comment: that was also the original plan, but my testers thought it was confusing that it didnt clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
for textField in [text1, text2, text3,text4, text5] {
    textField.text = ""
}
```

Because `text6` is a `UITextView`, put it separately.

```
text6.text = ""
```

Comment: text6 is a textview, would this still work with that? :)

Comment: thank you so much it worked with all the textfields, but when i add the textview, it says "value of type UIView has no member "text". do you know how i could fix this? :)

Answer (score 0):

In the function that is called on submission, first store the values of the text of the fields to variables, then after that set the text to nil for all of the fields. At that point you will have the info and the fields will be empty.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit? is it important that they each have a variable or is the "messagebody" variable enough?

Comment: They must each have a variable. Then, to make the message body, simply combine them into a `String` however you see fit.